# Start a new line after a multiple character group with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'd like to create a new line right after a character group is detected. The group consists of two or more star characters in a given text. My reg-ex knowledge is low, could anyone please help out with this.

I tried coding below but it fails to do what I want to accomplish. It puts a new line after each star, it should be done for two or more stars.

```
string result = "*1, **1, **1, ***1, *2, **2, *2, *2, **3, *3";

Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(result, @"[*(\\*\\*)+]", "\r\n$0"));
```

Result should be formatted like below; So when there's two or more starts together, start a new line;

```
*1,
**1,
**1,
***1, *2,
**2, *2, *2
**3, *3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex:

```
\s*(\*\*)
```

Replacement string:

```
\n$1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pW2tP5/1)

C# code would be,

```
string str = "*1, **1, **1, ***1, *2, **2, *2, *2, **3, *3";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s*(\*\*)", "\n$1");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/t2avKi)